# why are tips of airplane wings "bent' up?

Tags: aircraft-design

Why are the tips of wings on new aircraft folded up? Is it safety or efficiency that is the concern? I have done multiple searches and all I ever seem to get are wingtip shoes!

Comment: Yes, search on "winglets" not "wingtips" and you will find a bunch of info.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! The page that Greg linked to may answer your question. If it doesn't, please let us know what questions you still have after reading it. Thank you!